# Django model form how to output select Yes/No from Booleanfield

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to have a yes/no selection on a booleanfield.  The default widget is checkboxinput.  However if I override the default widget with Select I get a:
`NameError: Select is not defined`

I think this may be because I need to setup Yes/No to correlate to the boolean values in the booleanfield, but not sure how this should be done?

Model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    online_account = models.BooleanField()
```

Form:

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('online_account')
        labels = {
            'online_account': 'Do you have an online account',
        }
        widgets = {'online_account': Select()}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found (and tested with Django 1.9.6) [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amatellanes/9920823). It should do the trick:

```
from django import forms

class Form(forms.Form):
    field = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: x =='True', 
                                   choices=((False, 'No'), (True, 'Yes')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the **choices** in the template's boolean field

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

CHOICES_BOOLEANO_SIM_NAO = (
    (True, _('Sim')),
    (False, _('Não'))
)
class modelo(models.Model):
    """Model definition for LoteModalidadeEvento."""

    # TODO: Define fields here    
    e_bool_field= models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Este é um campo booleano'), **choices**=CHOICES_BOOLEANO_SIM_NAO)
```